# Playing mp3 in quodlibet displays "GStreamer output pipeline could not be initialized" error

Tags: debian, mp3, alsa, gstreamer, quod-libet

I'm running Debian testing x64 with all updates. I install quodlibet 2.4 from the repository and added mp3's to my library. When I play them, however, I receive an output error:

> GStreamer output pipeline could not be initialized. The pipeline might be invalid, or the device may be in use. Check the player preferences.

As far as I know, I've installed the relevant packages:

```
aptitude install -R alsa-base alsa-utils quodlibet gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-alsa
```

and configured my sound properly. After installing the packages and running `alsactl init`, sound works properly in VLC and my web browsers.

The output pipeline field the Playback tab of quodlibet's Preferences was blank, so based on relevant posts I found while searching ([**1**](https://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/issues/detail?id=1107), [**2**](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=96140)), I tried these options individually, as well as leaving the field blank:

```
alsasink device=hw:0,0
alsasink device=hw:0,1
alsasink device=default
gst_pipeline = alsasink
```

The [post on the Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=96140) (link #2 above) recommended running this command to determine the appropriate alsa device:

```
python -c 'import gst; print gst.element_factory_make("alsasink").probe_get_values_name("device")'
```

python -c 'import gst; print gst.element_factory_make("alsasink").probe_get_values_name("device")'

This gives me an error, however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<string>", line 1, in<module>
gst.ElementNotFoundError: alsasink
```

My system is running Python 2.7.5. What am I missing? How do I get quodlibet to play mp3 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using alsa, install version **0.10** of gstreamer's alsa plugin, not version 1.0.

```
aptitude install gstreamer0.10-alsa
```

and quodlibet should initialize the correct gstreamer pipeline immediately.

Quodlibet depends on version 0.10 of the other gstreamer plugins, as running `apt-cache depends quodlibet` will tell you:

```
jb@x:~$ apt-cache depends quodlibet
quodlibet
  Depends: python
  Depends: exfalso
  Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
  Depends: python-gst0.10
  Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
  Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
  Suggests: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
  Suggests: quodlibet-plugins
  Suggests: gstreamer0.10-gconf
 |Recommends: gstreamer0.10-alsa
  Recommends: <gstreamer0.10-audiosink>
    gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
    gstreamer0.10-alsa
    gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
    gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
```

Quodlibet 2.4 isn't compatible with version 1.0 of gstreamer's alsa plugin. Neither version of gstreamer's fluendo mp3 plugin are necessary either.

Answer (score 3):

Quodlibet uses gstreamer 1.0 since version 3.0 (see [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=108185)) so you need to install **gstreamer1.0-alsa** if you're using a later version.

Debian jessie/testing now uses v3.0.2 as of this post.

See the [package list](http://packages.debian.org/jessie/quodlibet).

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. Installing the gstreamer1.0-alsa package worked for me on Debian 8 (10-24-15)